# Add content from Text Boxes and Rich Text Boxes together in one

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET I am making a technical support program.

A user enters the error code, operating system, program/product name and a problem description.
When a button is pressed a new form is shown where I need all of this information to be put into one rich text box for the user to copy and then send to a tech support technician.

All entries except problem description are just text boxes.

However I am currently getting "cannot convert to long" using:

```
Private Sub GenericCode_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RichTextBox1.Text = My.Settings.ErrorCode And My.Settings.OS And My.Settings.ProgramName And My.Settings.ProbDesc
End Sub
```

Even though it is "RichTextBox1.Text". I tried doing the same thing by creating variables that contain all of the information before save them in My.Settings to do that.

Comment: Are you confusing `And` with `&` ?

Comment: `And` is not for concantenating, `&` is.

Comment: Replace your AND with the ampersand "&"

Comment: Also at the end of each MySetting do .ToString as they maybe an integer, long etc.. I dont know what these look like

Answer (score 0):

Another way to concatenate them. This adds spaces between them easier than `& " " &`

```
RichTextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", 
                                   My.Settings.ErrorCode, 
                                   My.Settings.OS, 
                                   My.Settings.ProgramName, 
                                   My.Settings.ProbDesc)
```

Comment: Depending on settings, might need to add `.ToString` to the end of each parameter

Comment: Not when using string.format also the tostring has been mentioned above in comment.